# Why Crystal php lib turns my non english latters into "?" signs? Is there a way around it?

Tags: php

Why [Crystal php lib](http://www.crystal-project.net) turns my non english latters into "?" signs? Is there a way around it?

So it happens if I try to walidate something or just post into DB. =( I know - I can not to use Crystal at all but I want to!

What can I do to solve such problem?

Comment: Mandatory reading: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see letters that turn into '?' it means that your string isn't in the correct format to handle the characters.  You can convert the text to unicode, or another format that can handle it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Here is the best article about it, written by the guy that made this web app:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html